# Scrapy get notification when all spiders are closed

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm using django to start scrapy crawls with

```
scrapyd = ScrapydAPI('http://localhost:6800')
spiders = scrapyd.list_spiders("default")
for spider in spiders:
        scrapyd.schedule("default", spider, list_id=list.id, spiders_number=3)
```

Do I'm able to connect all spiders related to single request based on `list_id`. I wish to get an information when all spiders finished their work. It is simple to send that information from spider to django (I can get an instance of django model and update it). But I do not know if current spider is the last one, which was running.

Is it possible to exchange data between spiders? Is there any well known approach to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is an event method in scrapy pipeline called `close_spider` which is called right before the spider is done and is getting closed.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

BUT, since you are looping through all spiders it would be useless.
The only solution I could think of is to call the notification on the last loop.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapyd-API doesn't run multiple spiders (jobs) at the same time,so get the list from `scrapyd.list_spiders("default")` in terminal, the last spider in the list will be the last one to run.
Then simply in that spider add

```
def close(self):
    #send notification()
```